# TypeScript, similar to Required, but converting all object properties to non-nullable

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, there is a `Required` type which converts an object properties to be defined

For example:

```
interface Person {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
}
```

`Required<Person>` would give us:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

My question is, similar to what `Required` is capable of, is there a type that converts nullable properties to non-nullable

For example:

```
interface Person {
  name: string | null;
  age: number | null;
}
```

I want it to be:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

:)

```
type Must<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: NonNullable<T[P]>;
}
```